# Should I provide a "Forgot Password" option for a one-time sign in Android application?

Tags: android, login, password

Right now we are developing an android application for a website. In the web site there is this "Forgot Password" option.

But should i have that option in my android application too??

Anyways i am using 1 time log-in in my application(needs to provide credentials only for the 1st time after installation), but i also have a logout option in the application. Since the user will not use the username and password often there is a probability that he will forget his password.

I rarely saw this option in android apps.

should i allow user to recover the password only through  the site, disabling it on the android app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several scenarios that a user may need to sign in again:

- The user may sign out accidently
- The user may be concerned about security and sign out after use the app each time (I know people who do this)
- The user may change phones
- The user may share his phone temporarily with another person who wants to use their credentials for the application

So if you assume that some of users are going to need to sign in again from time to time, you would expect some of them to have forgotten their password. If you make it hard for them to recover the password (like having to open a browser and go to web site to do it) then they might give up and use a different app.

Therefore you should make it as easy as possible, so include a method for letting your users recover their password from the application.